# The method or property Expo.Notifications.dismissNotification is not available on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, notifications, expo

**Error:**

The method or property Expo.Notifications.dismissNotification is not available on ios

**Environment info:**

SDK Version: 37.0.0
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): iOS 13.3
expo-cli 3.18.0
iPhone 11 Pro
expoAppVersion 1.12.0

**Repro steps:**

Call Notifications.dismissNotification on a notification received via Notifications.addListener